# AuthResult=Error_ on Authenticating using Sitecore Social Connector

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, sitecore, sitecore-social-connected

I've implemented Sitecore Social Connector to Login to my site using Facebook authentication as below:

```
ConnectUserManager connectUserManager = new ConnectUserManager();
if (!AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser().IsAuthenticated)
  connectUserManager.LoginUser("Facebook", true, (string)null);
else
  connectUserManager.AttachUser("Facebook", true, (string)null);
```

It's able to authenticate for a few Facebook users. But, for some of them I get

```
authResult=error_f01edd48-d480-45b2-94fb-ce1b9b88568a#_=_
```

Username and password provided are correct. Any idea on what might go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. How I resolved it?
 - I realized that my fb account had invalid email. So I set real email to my account, I try to login, and the magic happened. 
The bad thing here is that we cannot see the error message for that anywhere in the newtwork queries. 
**So, if some users are logged in, this means that your module works**. For these that are not able to login, they have some invalid data in their profiles.

What next?
 - How to catch and show the appropriate error message to the client? - maybe some pipeline or smth else... Will see :)
 - 
Good Luck!